# Fontello running on Ubuntu Server VM in Azure, but can't view in browser

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, ubuntu-server, fontello

I set up an Ubuntu Server VM on Windows Azure, specifically to run Fontello. I got the server running with no errors, but when I try to view the site in a browser, nothing appears. I've tried adding :3000 and /fontello to the URL with no success. I can SSH into the VM without issues, I just can't get it to display the site. Fontello is the only thing on the VM.

I'm not familiar with Linux at all, so I feel like I'm missing something really basic.

Comment: You have to define and unblock endpoints in Windows Azure

Comment: I defined an HTTP endpoint w/ port 80.

Comment: But You have to define port 3000, because Fontello is using it.

Comment: Worked! I tried this yesterday, but it didn't work for some reason. Works today though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an endpoint for port 3000 worked. I tried this yesterday with no success, but works today.